# Recalculate the height of a container div based on height of content within tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a page that has a sticky image sidebar on the left and tabbed content on the right of differing heights. The problem I run into is that the sticky sidebar is overflowing it's container when a shorter tab has been selected.

This behavior can be observed by clicking tab 2 and scrolling down the page. The image on the left should not overflow into the footer. Tab 1 shows the correct behavior.

Here is a code example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gayMjx

```
  <section class="js-pin-container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div class="js-pin-content">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p style="background: silver; height: 900px;">This dive is 900px tall.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p style="background: silver; height: 600px;">This dive is 600px tall.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p style="background: silver; height: 1200px;">This dive is 1200px tall.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't observe the behaviour you're describing... I've tested with Chrome and Explorer 11.

Comment: Select tab 2 and scroll down the page. You will see the pinned image overflow into the footer.

Comment: I can swear that NO. The image is only 250x250 so it's never taller than the tabs...

Comment: The image is supposed to scroll with you down the page but stop when it reaches the footer. It should never appear int he footer. Tab 1 is correct, tab 2 is not.

Comment: I'm writing an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @piyin answer I suggest not raising the `window.resize()` event each time.

The reason is that in the real world you may have several functions attached to this event and you want to avoid invoking all of them on each tab switch.

The better way of recalculating the height will be to expose the plugin method `recalculateLimits` and attaching it to the `activate` event:

Working example: [**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/536/Sidebar-pin-to-left-with-dynamic-tabs)

Exposing the method:

```
     ...
        $window.resize(function () { recalculateLimits(); });
        recalculateLimits();
        //This line expose the method
        this.recalculateLimits = recalculateLimits;
        $window.load(update);

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And then you can attach only it:

```
$(function() {

    //Attach pin:
    var pinSide = $(".js-pin-content").pin({
        containerSelector: ".js-pin-container"
    });
    //Create tabs:
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        activate:function(){
            pinSide.recalculateLimits();
        }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 8):

The problem is `pin` only updates its limits (`recalculateLimits`) when the window is resized, not when the contents of the container change. You could use a workaround so each time you open a new tab the `window` resize events are triggered. In other words, you could change your initialization of `tabs` plugin from:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

To:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  activate:function(){
    $(window).resize();
  }
});
```

Here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyYyag